# Verify that $\exp(-2aX_t)$ is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

**The Problem:**

Consider a Markov chain with the $N+1$ states $0,1,...,N$ and transition probabilities
\begin{align*} 
P_{ij} &= {N \choose j}\pi_{i}^{j}(1 - \pi_i)^{N-j}, \hspace{5mm} 0 \le i, j \le N, \\
\pi_i  &= \frac{1 - e^{-2ai/N}}{1 - e^{-2a}}, a > 0. 
\end{align*}
Note that $0$ and $N$ are absorbing states. Verify that $\exp(-2aX_t)$ is a martingale $[$or, what is equivalent, prove the identity $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_{t + 1})|X_t] = \exp(-2aX_t)$$]$, where $X_t$ is the state at time $t$ $(t = 0,1,2,...)$. Using this property show that the probability $P_N(k)$ of absorption into state $N$ starting at state $k$ is given by
$$ P_N(k) = \frac{1 - e^{-2ak}}{1 - e^{-2aN}}. $$

*Hint:* Use the fact that absorption into one of the states $0$ or $N$ in finite time occurs with certainty and that the relations
$$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_0)] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_n)] = P_N(k) \exp(-2aN) + (1 - P_N(k))  $$
hold (justify this).

**My Progress:**

As the hint suggests, I started by trying to prove the identity
$$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_0)] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_n)]. $$
Well, we can write the LHS as
$$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_0)] = \sum_{j=0}^{N}\exp(-2aj)\mathbb{P}(X_0 = j). $$
But this doesn't seem right because it seems a bit strange to be working with the pmf of the random variable $X_0$. Nevertheless, if I know that if I can get the same expression for $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_n)]$, I should be in good shape. However, this seems to a bit more unwieldy if I use the same approach. Indeed,
$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_n)] = \sum_{j=0}^{N}\exp(-2aj)\mathbb{P}(X_n = j),$$
where (I'm assuming), for each $j$,
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_n = j) = \sum_{i=0}^{N}P_{ij}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_0 = i). $$
That is, I'm just using the marginals and the Markov property to find the pmf of $X_n$. Again, this doesn't seem right to me; but I can't think of anything else to do...

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you first prove that $e^{-2aX_t}$ is a martingale? Note that for a martingale $M$, $ \mathbb{E}[M_t] = \mathbb{E}[M_0]$ holds for all $t$ (use the tower rule and the martingale property).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Well, I assumed that the "Hint" applied to proving that $e^{-2aX_t}$ is a martingale, as well. That said, I did try to prove that it is a martingale by proving the equivalent identity $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_{t+1})|X_t]= \exp(-2aX_t)$. I ran into similar issues there, though. By the "tower rule," I assume you mean the fact that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_{t+1})|X_t]] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(-2aX_{t+1})]$ (i.e., the "law of total expectation"). But then I'm just back trying to compute the expectation of $e^{-2aX_{t+1}}$...

Comment: This is a basic fact of martingale analysis - the expectation of a martingale is constant, and it seem to be the easy way to show your stated equality. Also, no, what I meant was $ \mathbb{E}[M_t] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[M_t|\mathscr{F}_0]] = \mathbb{E}[ M_0]$ (by evaluating the inner expectation). I also fail to see why similar issues would arise in showing the martingale property, since you only have to look at one step at a time. Concretely, can you compute $\mathbb{E}[e^{-2aX_{t+1}}|X_t = i]$?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Ok. (I suppose I should mention that I don't know anything about martingales; i.e., I've never worked with them before.) As to your question, I've got $$\mathbb{E}[e^{-2aX_{t+1}}|X_{t} = i] = \sum_{j=0}^{N}e^{-2aj}\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1}=j | X_t = i),$$ where $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1}=j | X_t = i)$ gets kind of messy...

Comment: There's many subtle things about martingales, but constant mean is not one of them (like, the above has a 1-line proof :P). I'm sure you can use this fact, it *has* to be why the Q asks you to show that this is a martingale first. As for the computation - it's not super messy, just a little bit: $ = \sum \binom{N}{j} \pi_i^j (1-\pi_i)^{N - j} e^{-2aj} = \sum \binom{N}{j} (\pi_i e^{-2a})^j (1-\pi_i)^{N-j} = (1 - \pi_i + \pi_ie^{-2a})^N$, where the last equaity is the binomial theorem. Can you now evaluate the final expression?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Yes, I got it. I failed to spot the application of the binomial theorem to get the nice expression (followed by the nice cancellation from the definition of $\pi_i$). Thanks.